# Hiding, or obfuscating the url path to files

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I'm allowing users to upload .jpg, .pdf .doc .xls files to my webserver under their own account, then they can later click on the filename to view the document in a browser, or on the case of .doc .xls, they download it via the default browser prompt.

I'm wanting to hide/obfuscate the url path so they don't know the exact path to get to the file, hoping to keep the files secure from other accounts/users.

I'm using php, apache

Here's and example path:

```
http://dev.site.com/administrator/account_files/1/documents/property_docs/1_68_1295980609myfile.pdf
```

How could I hide the url to something more like:

```
http://dev.site.com/1_68_1295980609myfile.pdf
```

the main purpose is to remove the reference to "administrator/account_files/...."

Is there something with apache's mod_rewrite that I could do?  I've read a few other posts where people used php's readfile() and used a different page, but I'm wondering if I'll have some performance problems with doing it this way.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It might cost you some performance, but it will probably not give any real problems when you use readfile. It's not much overhead. The file must be read anyway, so it's just a little overhead of running the PHP script.

I you do this, you can even choose to store the file in a folder outside your web root, or in a folder that is password protected by .htaccess. Both techniques won't keep readfile from reading the file, so both are good ways to really block the actual file from being read outside.

Comment: well, right now its using javascript to open a browser window and it has the url to the file there.  If I do it like this  <a href="openfile.php?file=myfile.pdf">view myFile</a>...then in the openfile.php page --> cleanse for sql or path traversal injection --> readfile("myfile.pdf") --> then output to the browser.  will this process be a significant performance overhead ... or is it it ok...is there a different way I should do this?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should force PHP to download that file:

```
<?php
$file = 'path/to/your/file.zip';
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/zip"); // change to a specific mime type
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to create a table in order to read and store the paths. For example, look at how sites like http://bit.ly work; essentially they assign a unique string to a URL and that's what you're looking to do.

There are a number of PHP scripts that can shorten URLs for you and thus mask the paths, just do a [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+url+shortener).

Comment: bit.ly still redirects to the original url. That means the user of the short url will still see the long url after the redirect. It might be better to skip this step altogether and just feed the file data through the short url, thus hiding the actual path completely.

Comment: I'm not saying that you do exactly as bit.ly says, the point of looking at how bit.ly and URL redirectors work is so that you can see the point of a routing table. That way you can then use PHP's readfile() function to get the file's content and serve it.